# CSS descendant selector exceptions

Tags: css, css-selectors

I read about the difference between descendant and child selectors and thought I had understood it but kept getting the same result whether I would use the first or the latter.

It took me a while to understand that there are exceptions to the rule and it's not always true that you don't target descendant tags when you would use child selectors. I don't know if I am wrong here but it seems that you have to have chosen a style on your descendent tags or you will still target the descendent tags even if you use child selectors.

Here is an example where I get the same result no matter what I use:

```css
ul#firstUl > li{
  color:red;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div >
   <ul id="firstUl">
      <li> Child </li>
      <li> Child </li>
      <li> Child </li>
      <li>
        <ul>
           <li> Descendant </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

As I have understood, the li tag with the text 'Descendant' should not had been targeted here but it is. So am I right that if the descendent tags haven't already been altered, you target them as well?

Comment: some properties are inherited like color and other apply to the element and all it's content like background so it's not about selector here

Comment: but if I have chosen a color for that tag it will not get the color red anymore. For instance if it would be: 

ul li{
  color: black;
}

ul#container > li{
  color:red;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

Then the color will not change to red.

Comment: because you have no element with ID `container`

Comment: Sorry it was just a misspelling. it should be the same result.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Larvpuqj/

Comment: Yes and the color remains black but the background still changes to lightblue. If you would change the background as well then it will not change either.

Comment: as I said *background apply to the element and all it's content* which is logical and this is how background shoud work. If you add background to body element you will cover all the elements of the page without selecting any of them

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.
So basically you're defining a color `red` for a `li` element. This color will be applied to **all** the element into the `li`. So the rule is applying correctly, however, setting up a default value (as I did below) will fallback to the `black` as soon as we're getting out of the scope of your css rule.

```css
li {
  color: black;
}

ul#firstUl > li {
  color:red;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div >
   <ul id="firstUl">
      <li> Child </li>
      <li> Child </li>
      <li> Child </li>
      <li>
        <ul>
           <li> Descendant </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```